# TSQL memory related queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I need to find if `/3GB` switch and `/PAE` is enabled on a server.

Also, I want to know the size of page file and physical RAM on the server.

I can check them manually but how can I check them using TSQL on both SQL 2000 and SQL 2005?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use WMI:

- The [Win32_OperatingSystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239(VS.85).aspx) class exposes the PAEEnabled property
- The [Win32_ComputerSystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394102(VS.85).aspx) class exposes the SystemStartupOptions property that contains the boot.ini parameters (pre-Vista)
- Post Vista you need to use the [Boot Configuration Data WMI Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb986746(VS.85).aspx) to see if /3gb is enabled, but I'm not sure *how*.

To run WMI queries, use [ExecuteWQL](http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/executewql-in-policy-based-management/) from the Policy Based Management framework (which you should be using anyway for the audit task you describe, see [Administering Servers by Using Policy-Based Management](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510667.aspx)).

[PowerShell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281954.aspx) can also read WMI. Ultimately, WQL queries can be run straight from T-SQL using [sp_OACreate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189763.aspx) and friends.

Answer (score 0):

this looks like one http://sugeshkr.blogspot.com/2007/12/check-if-3gb-is-configured-or-not.html

```
 If(Select Virtual_Memory_In_Bytes/1024/(2048*1024) from Sys.dm_os_Sys_Info) < 1
Begin

PRINT '/3GB Switch Not Configured in Boot.Ini (CHECK)'

End
```

Comment: but whatif the server actually has only e.g. 2GB and OS doesnt have that much available regardless of /3gb switch. ...like someone might have done it accidently